# str' object has no attribute 'squeeze'

Tags: bert-language-model, transformer-model, tokenize

i got  `AttributeError: 'BertTokenizer' object has no attribute 'encode` as i import `BertTokenizer` as

```
from pytorch_pretrained_bert import BertTokenizer, BertModel
```

when I changed to

```
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
```

the error was solved but another appeared with using `squeeze(0)` as i got

```
bert_embedding = encoded_layers[11].squeeze(0)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'squeeze'
```

Comment: Make sure that the data type of `encoded_layers[11]` is what you expect. Based on the error it seems that `encoded_layers[11]` is a string whereas you are expecting some kind of tensor/array.

Comment: yes it is string after i changed the importing library . i edit the code in the post

Comment: What is the type of `encoded_layers`? If you are using the `transformers` package from huggingface you should be able to access the embeddings (i.e. hidden layers) using the `hidden_states` attribute.

Comment: how can i do that please ?

Comment: You can check the type of a variable use the `type` function, i.e. `type(encoded_layers)`.

Comment: i got encoded_layers <class 'str'>

Answer (score 0):

The data type of `encoded_layers[11]` is not what you are expecting. Based on the error it seems that `encoded_layers[11]` is a string whereas you are expecting some kind of tensor/array. A [`BertModel`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.0/en/model_doc/bert#transformers.BertModel) from the `transformers` package by default returns an object of type [`BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions`](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/v4.16.0/en/main_classes/output#transformers.modeling_outputs.BaseModelOutputWithPoolingAndCrossAttentions), which stores multiple types of information of the model output such as the hidden states and attention tensors. From this object you can get the embeddings (i.e. hidden states) in multiple ways, depending on which embedding you are looking for. The last embedding can be retrieved by using the `last_hidden_state` attribute. If you want any of the earlier embeddings you would first have to use the `output_hidden_states` keyword in the `forward` method to make sure the model actually returns all hidden states, after which you can use the `hidden_states` attribute:

```py
from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
import torch

model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased")
tokens_tensor = torch.tensor([[101, 4825, 2038, 2715, 4799, 7251, 1998, 8397]])

# last embedding
with torch.no_grad():
      output = model(tokens_tensor)

output.last_hidden_state
# tensor([[[-0.0731, -0.2292,  0.3035,  ..., -0.4070, -0.0044, -0.5413],
#          [ 0.1083, -0.2389,  0.2601,  ..., -0.5643, -0.1055, -0.5517],
#          [-0.0290, -0.1246,  0.2876,  ..., -0.5169, -0.2024, -0.5582],
#          ...,
#          [ 0.1667,  0.3477,  0.3218,  ..., -0.6556, -0.2587, -0.7064],
#          [-0.0558,  0.2085,  0.5386,  ..., -0.4172, -0.2720, -0.7598],
#          [ 0.0320,  0.1543,  0.4174,  ..., -0.5563, -0.2501, -0.6365]]])

# all embeddings
with torch.no_grad():
      output = model(tokens_tensor, output_hidden_states=True)

output.hidden_states
# (tensor([[[ 0.1686, -0.2858, -0.3261,  ..., -0.0276,  0.0383,  0.1640],
#           [ 0.9370,  0.1125, -0.7017,  ..., -0.4128,  1.1211,  0.0241],
#           [-0.4053,  0.1127, -0.5541,  ...,  0.3581, -0.3911,  0.1235],
#           ...,
#           [-0.4134,  0.0977, -0.7046,  ..., -0.1922,  0.6822,  0.4226],
#           [-0.1209,  0.1080, -0.2337,  ...,  0.2583,  0.7219,  0.5589],
#           [ 0.1732,  0.4709,  0.1786,  ..., -0.3064,  0.7330,  0.9419]]]),
#  ...)
```

Comment: thanks a lot i will try it now but excuse me i followed code using encoded_layers[11] from model . does that the last or all embeddings  please ?

Comment: I don't know, since I am not sure from where you are copying code and what the goal of the code is.

Comment: the output should i get for the tensor i posted is in this form `bert_embedding tensor([[-0.0949, -0.2522,  0.0051,  ...,  0.4181,  0.0756,  0.3614],
        [-0.2266, -0.0338,  0.0196,  ...,  0.1263,  0.1874,  0.1383],
        [-0.2845, -0.2692, -0.1012,  ..., -0.1281, -0.3480,  0.1388],
        ...,
        [-0.1715,  0.1049,  0.0345,  ...,  0.0312,  0.1290, -0.4658],
        [-0.1872,  0.0719,  0.2143,  ...,  0.0416, -0.0184, -0.2138],
        [-0.3230, -0.1760,  0.0158,  ..., -0.1142,  0.1360, -0.0344]])`

Comment: Based on [the documentation of the `pytorch-pretrained-bert` package](https://pypi.org/project/pytorch-pretrained-bert/) it seems that 11th index of the `encoded_layers` list returns the state of the last to last BERT layer (given that there are 12 layers). In the `transformers` package, this can be done by using the index -1 on the `output.hidden_states` tuple or just using the `last_hidden_state` attribute.

Comment: If you want to simply convert the tensor to a 2d tensor you can simply use the `squeeze` method since the 3d tensor is of shape `(1, 8, 768)`. With regards to the difference in the numbers you would have to look at the implementations of the two libraries to see if there are any differences. You should still be able to use the old code since the `pytorch-pretrained-bert` package can still be installed and run, as this is what I did when comparing output from the two packages.